# In Windows 10, is there a way to deselect file(s) while in the 'Save As' window prompt?

Tags: windows-10, save-as, dialog

I just noticed that the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not deselect current file selection while navigating the *Save As* window prompt.  What would be the equivalent and native keyboard-input method, if any exists?

EDIT: Again, just to clarify, this is regarding the **Save As** dialogue window and not in standard `explorer.exe`.  Example photo:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a keyboard shortcut to "unselect" in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/78891/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-unselect-in-windows-explorer) Did you confirm if other mentioned options work or not?

Comment: @ankii It's not a duplicate, and yes I did try every answer suggested in that exact thread you referenced, **none** of them work in the *Save As* dialogue window.

Comment: As I'd assume you could simply click another folder or file to _change_ the selection, or close the dialog to cancel saving: what are you trying to achieve that needs one to be able to deselect? (Also: can one make multiple selections in Windows' Save dialogs?)

Comment: @Arjan There are plenty of scenarios in which one might want to deselect the highlighted file, especially when the end user prefers keyboard-only operation for the most part.  (If the process invoking the prompt accepts multiple files, then yes; otherwise, no).  What I find odd is that Ctrl + Arrow Keys still works and Ctrl + Space will select, just not deselect.

Comment: Are you (also) referring to a File Open dialog then? (Wondering how one could _save_ a file using multiple names. If it also applies to File Open, then please edit your question. For Save File this seems to be a bit theoretical, not [an actual problem that you face](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).)

Comment: @Arjan Sorry, I goofed!  I was thinking of the File Open dialog when answering your parenthesized question, but my question was particular to the Save As prompt.  However, I tried it real quick just now, and it seems the same behavior is exhibited in the File Open prompt as well, so the answer would potentially apply to both.